# WPF - MVVM Bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have problem with my application, especially with Bindings in WPF MVVM.
I created Model, ViewModel and View, this is part of my code (only this connected with my problem) When I click the button nemed : PointUp i want to see the amount of Team1 points. Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

View

```
    <Window x:Class="Tabu.Game
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tabu"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Tabu.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Game"  Height="600" Width="900" Background="Beige">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:TeamStatistic />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="PointUp" Command="{Binding AddPoints }" Content="+"/>
        <Label x:Name="PointsTeam1_label" Content="{Binding Team1.TeamPoints, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"/>
</Grid>
```

Model

'

```
namespace Tabu.Model
{
    public class Team
    {
        public bool IsTeamActive { get;  set; }
        public int TeamMiss { get;  set; }
        public int TeamPoints { get;  set; }
        public int TeamMistake { get;  set; }
    }
}
```

'

ViewModel

```
namespace Tabu.ViewModel
{
    class TeamStatistic : INotifyPropertyChanged

    {
        public Team Team1 = new Team();

        public int TeamPoints
        {
            get { return TeamPoints; }
            set { TeamPoints = value; OnPropertyChanged("TeamPoints"); }
        }

        public ICommand AddPoints
        {
            get { return new RelayCommand(() => Add_Points()); }
        }

        public void Add_Points()
        {
            Team1.TeamPoints++;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(params string[] propsName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged!=null)
            {
                foreach(string propName in propsName)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
        }
    }

public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Func<bool> canExecute;
        private readonly Action execute;

        public RelayCommand(Action execute)
            : this(execute, null) { }

        public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { if (this.canExecute != null) CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { if (this.canExecute != null) CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public Boolean CanExecute(object parameter) { return this.canExecute == null ? true : this.canExecute(); }
        public void Execute(object parameter) { this.execute(); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update your Binding like this.

```
<Label x:Name="PointsTeam1_label" Content="{Binding TeamPoints, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"/>
```

When you bind to Team1.TeamPoints you will not get the Notification from OnPropertyChanged which is inside your TeamPoints property.

Comment: Yes its true, my mistake :) it works, but only at the begining, the amount of points is still the same exual 0. The Bindings does nt refresh

Comment: Ah, ok I see the problem.
You update your Team1.Teampoints in your AddTeamPoints method and NotifyPropertyChanged will not be triggered again.
When your write OnPropertyChanged("TeamPoints"); after Team1.TeamPoints++; it'll be ok.

Comment: Thanks! i Didnt notice that .

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
public int TeamPoints
{
    get { return TeamPoints; } //should be Team1.TeamPoints
    set { TeamPoints = value; OnPropertyChanged("TeamPoints"); } //should be Team1.TeamPoints
}
```

Inside your `TeamPoints` property in `ViewModel` you return and set the same property `TeamPoints` from `ViewModel` but you should set from `Model` (`Team1`). You should return and set `Team1.TeamPoints`.

```
public int TeamPoints
{
    get { return Team1.TeamPoints; }  
    set { Team1.TeamPoints = value; OnPropertyChanged("TeamPoints"); }
}
```

And `Add_Points()`:

```
public void Add_Points()
{
    Team1.TeamPoints++;
    OnPropertyChanged("TeamPoints");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reckon it is because of AddPoints (the command binding). Since this command is binded & you are creating an instance of RelayCommand & returning each time it might be breaking the binding.

A better alternative with CommandBindings are to declare the property and initialize them in the Constructor of the view model.

Ex:

```
namespace Tabu.ViewModel
{
  class TeamStatistic : INotifyPropertyChanged

  {
    public Team Team1 = new Team();

    public int TeamPoints
    {
        get { return Team1.TeamPoints; }
        set { Team1.TeamPoints = value; OnPropertyChanged("TeamPoints"); }
    }

    private ICommand _AddPoints;

    public ICommand AddPoints
    {
        get { return _AddPoints; }
        set { _AddPoints = value; }
    }

    public void Add_Points()
    {
        Team1.TeamPoints++;
    }

    public TeamStatistic ()
    {
        _AddPoinss = new RelayCommand(Add_Points);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(params string[] propsName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged!=null)
        {
            foreach(string propName in propsName)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```